# How can I create a GROUP BY SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by

I have a table with multiple orders, when an order status is updated it created a new records so 1 order could have multiple records because of the different status's.

I have an Admin panel where the Admin can obviously see all the orders, but I don't want to be displaying every single update for each record because that could easily get out of hand. So I'd like to have the very latest record for each order. So if I have 7 records for order number 100, I want to show the very latest update for order number 100. I want each order to be like that.

I have a bit of a read online and tried to learn about MySQL Group By as I believe this is the best way to achieve what I want, but I can't seem to get it working I keep getting a message saying there is an error with my SQL statement

```
$query = '(SELECT * FROM orders 
           WHERE `order_status` != "Order Complete" 
           ORDER BY `order_update` DESC 
           GROUP BY `order_number`)'; 
$orderList = $conn->query($query);
```

This is the error I'm getting
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY `order_number`

I should've supplied my column structure. So I have an ID column, an Order Number column, an Order Status column, and finally an Order Date column. So the way I determine the most up to date status is by taking the Order Date (which is set as a timestamp).

**EDIT**
I want to achieve what I've put in my question but it's inside a loop. I loop through and display it all inside a table, so there could be 100 different orders which means 100 different order numbers, but I only want to display the latest status of each order which I can determine by using the Order Date column. Also I'm using PHP to build/execute the query

Comment: `GROUP BY` goes before `ORDER BY`

Comment: That gets rid of the error, but it doesn't give me the latest record it gives me the first

Comment: You should find a SQL tutorial.

Comment: Yeah that orders the display. What i'm saying is when I group the records by order_numer it obviously only displays 1 (hence why it's grouped) but the 1 it decides to display I want to be the very latest record

Answer (score 1):

First of all as mentioned in the comment above you have an answer to your error problem, GROUP BY is always before ORDER BY.

Second we need more data on the columns you have? maybe you have time and date of order? how do you determin which order is the latest?

How about something along those lines

```
$query = '(SELECT DISTINCT id, order_number, order_status, MAX(order_date) 
           FROM orders 
           WHERE `order_status` != "Order Complete"  
           ORDER BY `order_update` DESC, MAX(order_date)'; 
$orderList = $conn->query($query);
```

Just edit it to PHP syntax as im not familiar with it

Comment: I know this but i cannot comment yet and how would i ask for more info ?

Comment: or use the answer and later modify it ? ever thought about that? people need help why not contribute to the question rather than point out at useless things

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = '(SELECT * FROM orders 
           WHERE `order_status` != "Order Complete"           
           GROUP BY `order_number`
           HAVING `order_update`=MAX(`order_update`))';
```

Answer (score 0):

I obviously don't know 100% of what you are looking for, but you could likely achieve this without ever using a `GROUP BY` clause. You would typically only use `GROUP BY` when you are using aggregate functions (`COUNT`, `SUM`, etc.) It's a way of saying "hey, I want the count, sum, etc. of these specific columns."

Your query would probably be something closer to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE order_status != 'Order Complete' -- Consider revising, maybe just a boolean?
    AND order_number = 100
ORDER BY order_update DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Your query can vary pretty greatly depending on your DBMS, column names, etc. Feel free to comment with more info and I can help you more :)

EDIT: Just noticed that you did list MySQL as your DBMS. My mistake. This query should be sufficient with maybe minor tweaks.

Comment: Hi J. K. thanks for your answer. It's come to my attention I'm awful at writing questions! :) I want to achieve what I've put in my question but it's inside a loop. I loop through and display it all inside a table, so there could be 100 different orders which means 100 different order numbers, but I only want to display the latest status of each order

Comment: No problem Ben! Assuming you are using a backend language to build the query, you can feed in the `order_number` as a variable. Pseudo code:

for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    query = "select * from ... and order_number = /** some variable **/ ..."
    execute_query_here(query)
}

Comment: Yeah, I'm using PHP to build/execute the query